# Is there any method or function in python to name the sides of a 3-Dimensional Matrix, like in 2-D there is a Panda method Dataframedata

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I want to name/index the sides of the 3D matrix (Plane,row,column) in pythong code, like in 2D we can do it with the help od Panda methond Dataframe

> matrix = np.reshape((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), (3, 3))
>
> > df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, columns=column_names, index=row_names)
> >
> > > > print(df)

I want a result like, when we write A[0][0][0] then we can also track the what first index is representing and second index and 3rd.

Like in 2D we get something like

```
   a  b  c
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 0):

In pandas we can using multiple index

```
matrix = np.reshape((1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), (2,2,2))
df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x)for x in matrix],keys=np.arange(matrix.shape[2]))
df[0][0][0]
1
df[0][0][1]
3
```

Comment: the problem is indexing(naming) the sides of the matrix.
and later to retrieve the data according  those names, not with array index